# Redirect to show page on Responsive (small) list - admin-on-rest

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest

I'm doing an admin page using [admin-on-rest](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/) and I didn't find how to change where to redirect on a responsive list page.

The `<Responsive` `small={ ...` uses `<SimpleList>` and did not accept redirect such as in `<SimpleForm redirect="show">` or other options I've tried.

Bellow is the code, that's actually really similar to [the example](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Tutorial.html#responsive-list).

```
<Responsive
     small={
         <SimpleList
             primaryText={record => record.name}
             secondaryText={record => `${record.email}`}
             tertiaryText={record => `${record.score} score`}
         />
     } 
. 
. 
.
```

Is there any way to redirect to show page on small responsive page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A PR for this has been merged into the `next` branch (see [#1098](https://github.com/marmelab/admin-on-rest/pull/1098)).

This will be available in the upcoming `2.0.0` version